# How to retrieve User Identity in same request - Custom cookie authentication in Net Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to implement my own custom cookie authentication in .NET CORE 2.2. I have defined a custom cookie event to validate the cookie and check if the user has been locked out or similarly from the server.

This event gets called right after the user logs in (in the same request). My issue is `User.Identity.isAuthenticated` and the user's claims have not yet been set here (apparently this doesn't happen until the NEXT request)

From similar questions I have ensured that my `app.UseAuthentication();` is avove `app.UseMvc();` and that I instantiate my `ClaimsIdentity` object with an `AuthenticationType` as this `var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Basic");`

How can I work around the UserIdentity values not being set during the same request when the event is called right after logging in?

Note: my different managers are custom implementations - I do NOT use Microsoft.Identity

Startup.cs:

```
      services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
        AddCookie((options) =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
            options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/account/logout");
            options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);            
        });

        services.AddScoped<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();
```

CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents:

```
    public class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    private readonly ISignInManager _signInManager;
    private readonly HttpContext _context;

    public CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents(ISignInManager signInManager, IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _context = context.HttpContext;
    }

    public override async Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        //TODO retrieve user from database and check if he is locked out OR any values have changed
        var userPrincipal = context.Principal;

        var lastChangedClaim = userPrincipal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "Last Changed");

        if (lastChangedClaim == null || !await _signInManager.ValidateLastChanged(lastChangedClaim.Value))
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();

            await _context.SignOutAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
}
```

SignInManager:

```
        public int GetCurrentUserId()
    {
        //returns false
        if (!_context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return -1;

        Claim claim = _context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        if (claim == null)
            return -1;

        int.TryParse(claim.Value, out int currentId);

        return currentId;
    }

    public bool IsSignedIn(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        return _context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }

    public async Task SignInAsync(string email, string password, bool isPersistent)
    {
        await _context.SignOutAsync();

        // validate password
        var result = await _userManager.ValidatePasswordAsync(email, password);

        if (!result.Success)
        {
            return;
            // invalid login attempt
        }

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, result.User.Name),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, result.User.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim("Last Changed", result.User.LastChanged.ToLongDateString()),
        };

        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Basic");
        var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

         await _context.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        userPrincipal,
        new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
            IsPersistent = isPersistent,
            AllowRefresh = false
        });
    }

    public async Task<bool> ValidateLastChanged(string lastChanged)
    {
        var id = GetCurrentUserId();

        if (id == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserByIdAsync(id, CancellationToken.None);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return user.LastChanged > DateTime.Parse(lastChanged);        
    }
```

Comment: You don’t want to call both `context.SignOutAsync()` and `context.SignInAsync()` within the same request. The former will make the response contain a `Set-Cookie` header that clears all your cookies. It’s very possible that this clears the cookies you are trying to set there.

Comment: `_context = contextAccessor.HttpContext` – Please avoid storing the http context from a context accessor. Depending on the lifetime of your service, this can end very badly. So it’s better to simply not do that and only store the accessor and use it to retrieve the context as necessary. That being said, the `CookieValidatePrincipalContext` already contains the `HttpContext` so you don’t need the accessor in the events type.